# AMP version of e-commerce without plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, amp-html

I have two product pages of an ecommerce website: one made with Woocommerce (in WordPress) and one I coded my self in AMP.

[Here](https://www.construction.belram.be/product/nti-audio-xl2-sound-level-meter/) is the WordPress page, and [here](https://amp.belram.be/products/product-config-basic.html) is the AMP page. Not taking into account that the two pages are on two different subdomains, how would I redirect mobile users to the AMP version of the page ?

A similar question was asked, but it only specified how to do it for simple pages, not product pages.

Does anyone know how to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, You have to hard code this following lines in your theme functions.php if you don't want to use plugin.

Following ways to make it work as per your question

1. Create Metabox in Product Post Type of WooCommerce
2. Add Input Field to the Created Metabox
3. Save the Input Field via save_post action hook
4. Input the Specific URL for each Product
5. Fetch the saved data from Product and redirect if it is a mobile user.

**Step 1: Create Metabox**

```
//Create Metabox
function wc_49570125_register_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box('meta-box-id', __('Mobile Version URL', 'yourtextdomain'), 'wc_49570125_my_display_callback', 'product');
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'wc_49570125_register_meta_boxes');
```

**Step 2: Add Input Field**

```
// Add Input Field
function wc_49570125_my_display_callback($post) {
    $get_id = $post->ID;
    $get_value = get_post_meta($get_id, 'wc_mobile_version_url', true);
    ?>
    <p>
        <label><?php _e('Mobile URL to Redirect', 'yourtextdomain'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="wc_mobile_version_url" value="<?php echo $get_value; ?>"/>
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

**Step 3: Save the Input Field**

```
// save input field
function wc_49570125_save_meta_box($post_id) {
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    if ('product' != $post_type) {
        return;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['wc_mobile_version_url'])) {
        $mobile_version = $_POST['wc_mobile_version_url'];
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'wc_mobile_version_url', $mobile_version);
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'wc_49570125_save_meta_box');
```

**Step 4: Redirect mobile users to mobile version**

```
// redirect input field

function wc_49570125_mobile_redirect() {
    global $product, $post;
    if (is_product()) {
        $get_id = $post->ID;
        $amp_location = get_post_meta($get_id, 'wc_mobile_version_url', true);
        if (wp_is_mobile() && $amp_location) {
            wp_redirect($amp_location);
            exit;
        }
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'wc_49570125_mobile_redirect');
```

**Step 5: Add Discoverable Link for Google**

```
function wc_49570125_amp_google_link() {
    global $product, $post;
    if (is_product()) {
        $get_id = $post->ID;
        $amp_location = get_post_meta($get_id, 'wc_mobile_version_url', true);
        if ($amp_location) {
            ?>
            <link rel="amphtml" href="<?php echo $amp_location; ?>"/>
            <?php
        }
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'wc_49570125_amp_google_link');
```

I tested above code and seems it works well.

Comment: This is great Vignesh, it works! Thank you. There is just one more thing that I'm worried about. For AMP to be discoverable by Google, we need to add <link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html"> to the original page. How did you do that for all of your product pages and your home page?

Comment: Thanks again! If I want to add the same meta box for pages, can I use the same code by changing 'product' in Step 1 with 'page'? This way, I could also develop an AMP page for my homepage or products page and redirect mobile users to the AMP version just as you do for products.

Comment: Exactly you are right, Only thing you have to check the condition as well `if(is_product() || is_home() || is_page() || is_front_page()) `

Comment: It works perfectly! Last question: have you managed to run a website with a cart and payment flow both in AMP and WooCommerce using these methods? We are still considering our options here. What frightens me is the add to cart process. WooCommerce has its special way to handle this. Wouldn't that be a nightmare to maintain and track sells using two differents ways to add to cart? For example, do you think it is feasible to use custom PHP code and use it both in AMP and WooCommerce. I am asking because my colleagues would like an easy way to add products while I want AMP's speed for our shop.

Comment: No i haven't manage any website using AMP, but i guide some ideas where once the order is completed in your amp mobile site, then using woocommerce rest api you can create the order in your main site so that you can track the order and delivery using this option. For more information https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order

Comment: Meanwhile you can accept my answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work